# firebase authentication problem is Expecting binder but got null

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

In `build.gradle` I write this and I have problem `Expecting binder but got null!` and I got this error after I write this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In debug console I got this:

```
E/SurfaceSyncer(10071): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  (10071): Expecting binder but got null
Application finished.
```

Comment: Did the application crash or just threw this warning in console? If you are using Android Studio, File->Invalidate cache and restart might help.

Comment: I use a vscode in this error

Comment: and warming in console I do as you said I got this warming, Will it make bug or crash in future?

Answer (score 0):

The warning `Expecting binder but got null` is not related to flutter and is thrown by android OS itself. It's not going to do anything to your app so it is safe to ignore it.

You can found more about this [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119128).